# Boost Inductor Voltage calculations

Tags: voltage, inductor, boost, power-factor-correction

This is probably a stupid question, but please bear with me. 
I'm making a boost inductor for PFC and I just wanted to make sure I'm calculating for the voltage correctly. Is the equation:

\$N =  \frac{V\times10^8}{4fA_eB} 
\$

Or does that only apply to transformer windings?

If it does apply to inductors, should \$ V =V_{boost}\$ or rectified \$ V_{in}\$?

Comment: Neither. V should be the voltage "across" the inductor. Anyway, I wouldnt calculate the number of turns with Faraday equation. Instead, if you have calculated the required inductance (L) then go for \$L=A_L \cdot N^2\$. Wind a few (at least 10) turns to the core, measure its inductance and calculate \$A_L\$ from the equation I gave. Then calculate required N for required L.

Comment: While inductance is incidentally relevant, it's needed for ripple calculations, the core volt.second_max is is vital, to avoid the inductor saturating. This cannot be measured with an \$A_L\$ estimate, only with knowledge of permitted Bpeak and \$A_e\$ as above, or by measuring inductance with varying current and seeing where it collapses.

Comment: @iuppiter Please show said core with such a ridiculously low saturation current. Most cores for PFC are irin powder and work up to and beyond 1 T.

Comment: @winny I was actually planning on adding an air gap to increase the reluctance in order to use a higher \$B\$ which was suggested to me by another user. I'ts that I already have a bunch of E cores on hand and I really didn't want to wait another week or spend the money to buy cool μ cores.

Comment: Still, which core has a Bmax of .2 mT?

Comment: @winny MnZn PC40 cheap amazon crap. This is all for learning purposes. At least thats what I gathered from the datasheet.

Comment: PC40 goes to at least 1000 times that. Read the datasheet.

Comment: @winny Really? Maybe I was reading it wrong. What's the highest operating frequency without significant core loss and nasty eddy currents? The chinese vendor at amazon was absolutely no help when I asked for a datasheet, they just told me the \$A_L nH/N^2\$ I was getting the info from TDK

Comment: @winny Sorry I meant .2T which would be 2000 Gauss, I'm a little sleepy.

Comment: No, air-gap gives you higher H.

Comment: There you go. For PC40, you will be Bsat limited unless you go DCM at very high frequency.

Answer (score 1):

If your core Bfield is swinging linearly between + and - \$B\$ Tesla peak, at a frequency of \$f\$ Hz, in a core of area \$A_e\$ square metres, then the peak square wave voltage per turn is \$4 f A_e B\$ in volts. I'm not going to try to guess in what unit system your \$10^8\$ factor might be appropriate. As you see, keep it all in SI and it tends to be a bit easier.

Obviously you can invert that to get a Bfield slew rate, when a certain volts/turn is applied to the inductor. *This* is the way round to use the relation when you are figuring out how much the field slews when you connect Vin or Vboost to your inductor for a certain time.

Comment: I found that equation in a manufacturer datasheer where \$B\$ is in gauss (which I found weird) and \$A_e\$ is measured in \$ cm^2\$(which I also found weird).  I'm guessing that's where the \$10^8\$ factor comes from.

Comment: You'll notice that in the answer, all I did was nail the units and measures of all the terms you used. I hate conversion factors. I hate equations without defined terms. I hate it when equations only hold up for certain waveforms, or certain measures like peak, rms, or peak to peak without spelling out which.

Comment: it seems to work for transformer windings where \$N =  \frac{400V\times10^8}{4\times 100kHz\times 1.78cm^2 \times 1800 gauss}\$ returned 31.21098627 turns. Does that sound right?

Comment: In the datasheet the equation was actually for \$B_{max}\$, I just turned it around. Can I get rid of that stupid \$10^8\$ and just use teslas and \$m^2\$ ?

Comment: @iuppiter who cares whether the equation in stupid units is right? Do it in furlongs, fortnights and hundredweights for all I, or anybody else in their right mind, would care. Use SI. If you care to repeat the calculation using square metres for Ae, and Tesla for peak field, then I might be bothered to comment.

Comment: @iuppiter One **very important point**. \$f\$ is only relevant for transformers. You have an application with variable times. As I pointed out in my answer, use the times to understand the change in B. As the PFC works through the cycle, Vin and so the on times will change. The inductor must not saturate even with the worst longest time. You should work out exactly what that means, but I suspect that replacing the 4 with a 2 in that equation, if your PFC has a fixed frequency, will cater for the worst case on time.

Comment: What is the 4 about anyway? I was told to use 4 for square waves instead of 4.44 which is supposed to be for sinusoidal waves.

Comment: @i **That's** why I don't like waveform-specific equations. What's the 4.44 about? Hint, it rolls up a factor of \$2\pi\$, can you see it? No, neither can I. The B slew rate is defined by the rate of change of flux in the \$A_e\$ area of the core. **That** will tell you where the 4 or the 4.44 factors (or my possible factor of 2) come from, and why you need to know the worst case 'on' time for PFC inductor use. Did I mention that \$f\$ is only relevant for transformers?

Comment: I'm gonna plug your method into Excel and see the results.

Comment: \$N =  \frac{V\times10^4}{4fA_eB} 
\$ works for units of testlas, but without \$10^4\$ the result is totally incorrect.

Comment: @iuppiter you did use \$m^2\$ for units of \$A_e\$, didn't you? \$cm^2\$ doesn't cut it. By the way, is that \$c(m^2)\$ or \$(cm)^2\$? That's another reason I don't like raising anything other than base units to powers. When I do \$A_e\$ calculations, when the data sheet gives \$mm^2\$, I tend to write \$365\mu\$ \$ m^2\$, with the spacing.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, went back and double checked and it still gave me a weird N.  maybe if you lay the equation out for me I'll get it.

Comment: I even re measured the core it's \$180mm^2\$

Comment: How'bout you link the data sheet, then I don't have to guess

Comment: \$N =  \frac{V\times10^8}{4fA_eB}\$ is appropriate in CGS units of measurement. FYI